# Review Suspension: Poor Audits, Poor Reviews, or Both?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension

I’m hoping a moderator will consider reviewing a suspension I received due to two failed audits in the *First Answers* queue—and, if possible, offer feedback on these audits.

- The [first audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/29778264) provided a useful algorithm to solve the problem, but in a different language than the question was tagged with (as fully acknowledged by the author).
- The [second
  audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/30207174) was a
  code-only answer that was incorrect for technical reasons, which were called out in the comments (though obviously not visible during the audit).

Neither were *good* answers. Had I been more diligent, I would have left comments—and, perhaps, that alone is justification for the suspension? I certainly recognize that would have been constructive here, especially as these were first answers. I also could have edited the second one to fix the excess indentation in the code block. And, of course, I arguably should have caught that these were audits.

That said, I wouldn’t have *flagged* or *recommended deletion* for either, since they were both sincere attempts to answer the question, even if the solutions weren’t useful. For that reason, these seem like poor audits, if nothing else. If I *should* be flagging these, I’d like to know. My understanding remains that reviewers should not be evaluating posts for technical accuracy, and that code-only answers are acceptable, even if we should encourage explanations.

That said, I think my overall record in both this queue and *LQP* is strong, and hope you’ll consider lifting the ban. Alternatively, if I’m fundamentally misunderstanding my responsibilities as a reviewer, I’m hoping you’ll offer advice so I can improve my record when my suspension is up.

(It’s worth noting there’s some contesting of my record in SOCVR due, in particular, to me choosing “Looks Okay” for a number of code-only answers.)

Comment: A whole bunch of folks missed the "answer" box when posting their opinions on this matter, so an extended conversation had to be [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238711/discussion-on-question-by-jeremy-caney-review-suspension-poor-audits-poor-revi).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cody Gray was kind enough to talk through the issue with me in SOCVR—and I now have a better understanding of what I was (indeed) doing wrong. I suspect others may learn from my mistakes, so I've summarized and excepted relevant parts of the conversation below.

#### TL;DR:

- My [first review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/29778264) as acceptable, though the post could have benefited from light editing.
- My [second review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/30207174) was wrong—but not because it was a code-only or incorrect answer, but because it was "not even wrong".
- Fundamentally, I was confusing the *NAA* rules for *LQP* and *LA*; the review queues allow (and indeed *expect*) judgment calls regarding content that "contributes nothing to the site".

#### First Audit: *Wrong programming language, but useful as pseudocode*

For [the first audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/29778264), this was primarily a bad audit, and Cody has since undeleted it ([source](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/53359879#53359879)):

> I think the first answer was completely reasonable. It wasn't just someone cluelessly posting a solution in the wrong language. They acknowledged that it was in the wrong language, but were trying to explain an algorithm. That seems OK to me. A downvote is not unjustifiable, but deletion is.

That said, Cody also concurred with [Jeanne Dark's comment](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/53359890#53359890) that the answer would have benefited from [some light editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69035800/revisions) to touch up the grammar and clarify the answerer's intent ([source](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/53359894#53359894)):

> It's difficult to think of any case in a review queue where "Looks OK" is completely justified. There's almost always something that can be done to improve a post.
>
> I will definitely echo Jeanne's remark about reviewing not being a binary choice between "flag" and "Looks OK". There are plenty of other options. Just because something doesn't need to be immediately deleted (and thus flagged/voted to delete), that doesn't mean it's "OK".

#### Second Audit: *"Not Even Wrong"*

For [the second audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/30207174), Cody suggests that this was a bad call on my part, and warranted the failed audit ([source](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/53359881#53359881)):

> The second answer was complete trash. It wasn't even trying to be relevant, and looks more like trolling to me. Maybe you couldn't tell because all of C# is Greek to you? That's OK; hit Skip. Don't say stuff looks OK that doesn't. I think you made the wrong call on that one.

This one confused me initially, because it was my understanding (based largely on [the *LQP* guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)) that reviewers should not be evaluating posts for technical accuracy, and that wrong answers shouldn't be flagged. Cody confirms this ([source](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/53360135#53360135)):

> Now, we don't generally want to delete answers simply because they're wrong, because (A) we might be wrong, too, and (B) wrong answers can still serve in an advisory capacity about what not to do. (Especially when they're recommending a common, but flawed, approach. If that isn't mentioned by answers, people will think it was forgotten and possibly leave more answers mentioning it. That's much worse. Just downvote the wrong answers instead; it is much more useful.)

But additionally carves out an exception for "not even wrong" answers ([source](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/53360049#53360049)):

> I would also generally say that you shouldn't vote to delete incorrect answers. But I have a different opinion about "not even wrong" answers. That one falls into the latter category. It doesn't even attempt to answer the question, even though it masquerades as an answer by having a code block.

This really gets into the heart of my confusion, which is that I was applying roughly the same criteria I use for *NAA* flags for both *LQP* and *LA* ([source](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/53360109#53360109)):

> The lesson should be more of:
>
> 1. Pay more attention, actually reading the answer and the question, and evaluating whether it even attempts to answer the question. Although something like this probably couldn't be flagged as NAA, that doesn't mean it's an appropriate contribution or should stick around.
> 2. Almost nothing in the review queues "Looks OK", so you probably need to do something.
> 3. If you aren't sure, or don't have the time to look carefully, then just "Skip".
>    Fundamentally, reading your other comments, I think you are confusing the guidance that is meant to be very specific to NAA flags with the general guidance for how to review.

And, in fact, part of the issue is that I was deliberately *removing* both my subject-matter expertise as well my personal judgment from my reviews, just as I have (successfully) done for *NAA* flags. But, as Cody notes ([source](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/53360148#53360148)):

> We still want people to be able to exercise their judgment and subject-matter expertise when reviewing answers, deleting them when they think that the post is harmful or contributes nothing to the site.

That requires paying closer attention to the *code* than I have been when reviewing *LQP* and *LA*; normally, I treat a code block as a black box, since I didn't see it as my role to evaluate technical accuracy. But to evaluate "not even wrong", I need to have some basic idea of what the question asks and what the code is doing.

#### *NAA* Flags

On a final note, even though answers like the second audit aren't suitable for the *NAA* flag, Cody suggests using a custom flag in these cases ([source](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/53359913#53359913)):

> Even that second case where I said it was "complete trash" would probably not be suitable for a NAA flag. If a mod wasn't paying close enough attention, they could end up declining that flag. (There are no mod audits!) So, a custom flag is probably more appropriate, or, of course, directly voting to delete when the queue allows it.

Comment: So, do we need to add an image to [Shog's Apples](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/616624) that expresses, "not *even* wrong"?

Comment: We need an image that's just a box. who knows whether or not there's an apple inside.

Comment: @KevinB Or [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Apple_Computer_Logo_rainbow.svg)? (After suitable shrinkage.)

Comment: @AdrianMole That's *oddly* wrong.