# Failed Review Audit: Upvoted answer; failed due to "Other Action"

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, first-answers

I just encountered a review audit for [an answer that has eleven upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963819/why-use-your-application-level-cache-if-database-already-provides-caching/69541938#69541938). I immediately identified it as a review audit, gave it an upvote, and then chose *Other Action*. Because I chose *Other Action* instead of *Looks OK*, however, it treated it as [a failed audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/30309595).

Obviously, *Other Action* can be *ambiguous*. But I'd expect that when the actual action is an *upvote* that should satisfy the review audit criteria. And, indeed, in the *LQP* queue, just clicking upvote would have satisfied the audit criteria.

This appears to be a bug that was reported to [Meta Stack Exchange just yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371701/unable-to-pass-first-question-first-answer-review-audits).

Unfortunately, this also resulted in a review suspension. As such, I'm hoping a moderator will consider lifting the review suspension since the upvote was the correct action—and especially since this appears to be due to a known bug in the system.

**Note:** This is the *opposite* issue as discussed in [I didn't pass when I downvoted a deleted answer that had negative score?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412941/i-didnt-pass-when-i-downvoted-a-deleted-answer-that-had-negative-score) That question addresses a scenario where the user downvoted a *NAA*, but failed to flag it. My scenario is that I *upvoted* a high-quality answer, but chose *Other Action* instead of *Looks OK*.

Comment: I believe it's the same underlying bug in the review queues. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371701 which is also linked in a comment on the suggested duplicate target, that mentions your case explicitly.

Comment: if you know it's an audit, just hit skip. Why bother having to click through the "Congratulations! that was an audit!" screen?

Comment: @KevinB: If I know it's an audit, why not just pass the audit? I assume if I skip an audit I'll just be presented with another audit soon after. But maybe that's an invalid assumption. Regardless, that doesn't address the key concern here.

Comment: to skip the "congratulations" screen. You gain nothing for "passing" an audit other than not failing it.

Comment: It doesn't address the concern, it bypasses it, while also preventing you from incorrectly failing audits due to the nature of audits.

Comment: @cigien: You're correct that this is the same issue as the bug reported on Stack Exchange. Thank you for identifying that. Based on that, I've updated my question to link to the bug report, and retagged it to be a [tag:discussion], with more focus on my review suspension, rather than the [tag:bug].

Comment: @KevinB: I see what you're saying now. Lesson learned; I will start doing that in the future. The audit system is certainly a source of frustration. I want reviewers (including myself) to improve the quality of our reviews. But it's not always clear that the audit system is accomplishing that.

Comment: Ok, that's reasonable. I've retracted my close vote as duplicate. I've also edited the question a bit to remove the commentary about why you made edits, etc. In general, try to avoid meta-commentary like that (even though this is meta ;)).

Comment: As an aside, the [other failed audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/30207174) that caused this to result in a suspension is **completely valid**, but one which [I was already suspended for](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412666/3025856), and which [exposed a misunderstanding in my rubric](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412690/3025856). Thankfully, @Cody set me straight, and I have since altered how I review to accommodate the feedback. Regardless, I wouldn't expect the same audit to count toward a _second_ suspension.

Comment: I think it is still the same problem, you just hit it from the other side. The root cause is still the same. Someone had already lifted your review suspension, so there seems to be little more to do here. Let me know if you disagree.